# how to get specific product attribute list and option?

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product

How can i get specific product attribute list and price with product id ? is it possible to get product options like color , size and ... only with product id ? i want to add a php code to root of magento on host and when call it from browser it`s show me details of product .

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it depends on the attribute i.e it we saving and text in product it will be get using

> $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>
> echo $_product->getData('product_attribute_code');

to get price of product

> $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>
> echo $_product->getData('price');

if you want product option like color and size use slow code

First get the id by label and than perform addField to filter on collection

> $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>
> $color_id = $_product->getData('color');
>
> $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
>
> $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute('color'); if
>   ($attr->usesSource()) {
>
> echo $color_text = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($color_id); }

Comment: How can i know what is attribute id that added to the product ?

Comment: you will get an id from manage attribute table.